# В панели управления клиентами пропадают и появляются устройства с именем "-" и разными MAC адресами

Tags: сеть, администрирование, роутер, d-link

[image: Панель управления клиентами]
Недавно заметил, что в панели управления клиентами пропадают и появляются устройства с именем "-" и разными MAC адресами. Ради интереса пробовал hard reset, смену пароля, поведение всё равно не изменилось.

Что это может быть?